# magento 2 How to get registration page custom value on my account frontend

Tags: magento2

Currently Using magneto 2.3

> Already add a custom field [Spouse Name] on registration page

[image]

> Now i want to show on my Account frontend. How to show??

[image]

Comment: Did you created any customer attribute for spouse name?

Comment: Yes already created customer attribute as spouse name. I want show value on my account font-end

Comment: What is the attribute code?

Comment: attribute code is 'spouse_name'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> app\code\Vendor\Magento\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" template="Vendor_Module::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Magento\view\frontend\templates\account\dashboard\info.phtml

Add below code

```
<?= 'Spouse name: '. $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('spouse_name')->getValue() ?>
```

Finally info.phtml will look like

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info $block */
?>
<div class="block block-dashboard-info">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Account Information')) ?></strong></div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="box box-information">
            <strong class="box-title">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Information')) ?></span>
            </strong>
            <div class="box-content">
                <p>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getName()) ?><br>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getEmail()) ?><br>
                    <?= 'Spouse name: '. $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('spouse_name')->getValue() ?>
                </p>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.account.dashboard.info.extra'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="box-actions">
                <a class="action edit" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('customer/account/edit')) ?>">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Edit')) ?></span>
                </a>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getChangePasswordUrl()) ?>" class="action change-password">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password')) ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
            <div class="box box-newsletter">
                <strong class="box-title">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Newsletters')) ?></span>
                </strong>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <p>
                        <?php if ($block->getIsSubscribed()): ?>
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You are subscribed to "General Subscription".')) ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You aren\'t subscribed to our newsletter.')) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-actions">
                    <a class="action edit" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('newsletter/manage')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Edit')) ?></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Spouse name will be displayed under `Contact Information` mail address. You can add abouve line wherever you want

**Edit**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,  ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.8', '<')) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'customer Attr',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'custom_attribute')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit'
                ]
            ]);
            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not showing in Contact Information.

Comment: Please check in database whether the value saved or not.

Comment: Value saved in 'customer_entity_varchar'. value is available

Comment: Please update your setup file code to investigate. Because my customer attribute is showing now.

Comment: Can you please share me setup file??.

Comment: I have updated pls check.

Comment: You are Override through the templates. i m right?

Comment: Yes. I have override info.phtml through template

Comment: But I want to Override through module.

Comment: I have updated please check and let me know.

Comment: Great it's Working. But If any case i have to create own block and show spouse name then how to use?

Comment: Same code you have used in phtml...Just load customer object and load custom attribute.